# Фабричный метод

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте, возможно ли следующий код переделать под порождающий паттерн Фабричный метод, и если можно то как:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testNasledovanie
{
    class Vector
    {
        public int[] arr;
        private const int size = 4;

        public virtual void  Input()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initialzing");
            arr = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        public virtual void Output()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your vector");
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        }

        public virtual int Ymova()
        {
            int max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
            }

            return max;
        }

        ~Vector()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("destructor vector is called.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Maxtix : Vector
    {
        public int[,] array;
        private const int size = 4;

        public override void  Input()
        {
            array = new int[size, size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    array[i, j] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }

        public override void Output()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your 2D array");
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(array[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public override int Ymova()
        {
            int max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    if (array[i, j] > max) max = array[i, j];
                }
            }

            return max;
        }

        ~Maxtix()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("destructor matrix is called.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int userSelect;

            Vector baseobj = new Vector();

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter '0' if you want to work with vector and 1 with matrix");
                userSelect = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (userSelect == 0)
                {
                    baseobj = new Vector();
                    baseobj.Input();
                    Console.WriteLine("max is " + baseobj.Ymova());
                }
                else if (userSelect == 1)
                {
                    baseobj = new Maxtix();
                    baseobj.Input();
                    Console.WriteLine("MAX IS " + baseobj.Ymova());
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }

                baseobj.Output();

            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Данный код позволяет создавать объекты классов вектор или матрица (есть небольшое меню). Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `Console.ReadKey();` в финализаторе? o_O

Comment: я делал задержку чтобы показать что работает деструктор, а насчёт моего вопроса, это вообще возможно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код ужасен. Например полным отсутствием инкапсуляции, а также неразделением обязанностей. Вектор не должен (нет, не так: НЕ ДОЛЖЕН!) заниматься чтением данных с клавиатуры.

Разделите его на части:

```
class Vector
{
    private const int size = 4;
    private int[] arr = new int[4];

    Vector(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        arr[0] = a;
        arr[1] = b;
        arr[2] = c;
        arr[3] = d;
    }

    // input - не дело вектора, перенесли

    // называть функции транслитом - отвратительно
    // никогда больше так не делайте
    public virtual int Max()
    {
        // инициализировать надо не нулём, а минимальным возможным значением
        int max = int.MinValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > max)
                max = arr[i];
        }

        return max;
    }

    // деструктору не место в массиве, у вас нету неуправляемых данных
    // (и вы наверное не знаете, что это такое)
}

static class VectorFactory
{
    public static Vector InputFromConsole()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter vector values (one per line):");
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return new Vector(a, b, c, d);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, знаю что "быдлокод", например деструктор требовал препод, транслит это да, это  ужас просто руки не добирались до этой программы,  а смотрите в вашем коде только для вектора реализовано или как? потому что у меня там вприцнипе еще матрица есть. А неуправляемые данные это те данные которые я так понял не используються в программе?

Comment: @M-Misha-M: Это плохо, что препод требовал деструктор. Значит, он совсем не понимает язык. Учите по другим источникам. У меня реализовано только для вектора, с матрицей по идее то же самое.

Comment: @M-Misha-M: Неуправляемые данные — это данные, которые не управляются системой управления памяти .NET. надо специально потрудиться, чтобы такие заполучить. Короче говоря, не парьтесь, это к вашей проблеме не имеет отношения.